# Use gmail in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

We've recently switched to using GMail at work for a variety of different reasons after having our own Outlook Exchange for a while. At present everyone is still used to using the Outlook interface instead of GMail. We've managed to set the accounts up in Outlook successfully and it all worked for a day. After that we started getting warnings from GMail because it considers Outlook to be a "less secure app".

For security reasons my boss does not want to enable the "Allow less secure apps" option for each users GMail account but as far as I know that is the only way to use Outlook with GMail.

Is there a way we can enable "Allow less secure apps" but only for Outlook? Or is Outlook now off the table, so to speak?

We are using Outlook 2016, version 1811.

Comment: @DanielB At present all of our Outlook apps have been blocked so maybe there is a setting somewhere that needs updating but I can't find it at the moment

Comment: Well maybe I remembered wrong. Looks like Outlook doesn’t support this, after all. Just use Two Factor Authentication and App Passwords.

Comment: This is not configurable from Outlook side. Have you contacted Gmail support on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can enable acces to less secure APPs.
In the following link you can find the Google Help page for less secure Apps:

[Control access to less secure apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en)

Comment: Isn't that an all or nothing setting? As I mentioned in my question we can't allow everything through. If there is a way to whitelist certain less secure apps that would be fine though but I can't tell that from this answer.